# Collectd - How to get version installed

Tags: collectd

I have installed collectd using `sudo apt-get install collectd`. Is there any command to get the current installed version of Collectd?

I tried `collectd -v`. Apparently it does not work. I do not see any option to get the version.

Answer (score 5):

`apt-cache policy collectd` will show the version installed (as well as other available versions and their sources)

Answer (score 1):

Run `collectd/bin/collectdctl`
It prints out the version.

Answer (score 0):

Use `/usr/bin/collectdctl` on RHEL 7 or CentOS.

On RHEL 8 you can use `collectd -h` this will also print the version.